# ContentFrame.Navigate - Storyboard not showing at the Page_Load

Tags: silverlight

I have a simple silverlight Navigation Application.

I need to start a Storyboard when a Page is navigated on a content frame.

At first everything seemed to work fine.  But now I need to do some treatment (that takes about 3 seconds) when the Page loads, just before showing the Storyboard.

Now I do not see my Storyboard animation anymore.  Even if the Storyboard is started after my data is loaded.

I can emulate my problem using a Thread.Sleep like that it does the same thing :

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Storyboard1_Test.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the Xaml of your page and Storyboard, or a minimum example that duplicates your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering UI changes from an event handler sometimes have this kind of issues. Usually using [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method solve it.

So just try lunching  `Storyboard1_Test.Begin();` from the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Some code (hope you don't mind i'm using VB.NET):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                         Storyboard1_Test.Begin()
                       End Sub)
```

By using the dispatcher.BeginInvoke you verify that the job is excuted on the UI thread when the thread is available.

Comment: Cool, that works. But I'd really like some more explanation on why its working like that... I find it pretty confusing :/

Comment: @danbord: I believe that by using the dispatcher.BeginInvoke you verify that the job is excuted on the UI thread when the thread is available. Since using the UI Event handler is executed on the UI thread as well, it may be unavailable to execute other UI changes.
So the dispatcher just queues it.